# rails app:update conflicts - cleanest way to select file content?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to upgrade from Rails 5.0 to Rails 5.1.1.

Running `rails app:update` results in various conflicts where Rails 5.1.1 has a file with the same name as Rails 5.0, and I'm asked what I want to do about it.

The 'diff' for 'development.rb' look like this:

```
     config.cache_store = :memory_store
     config.public_file_server.headers = {
-      'Cache-Control' => 'public, max-age=172800'
+      'Cache-Control' => "public, max-age=#{2.days.seconds.to_i}"
     }
   else
     config.action_controller.perform_caching = false
@@ -30,8 +30,6 @@
   config.action_mailer.raise_delivery_errors = false

   config.action_mailer.perform_caching = false
-  host = 'localhost:3000'                     # Local server
-  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { host: host, protocol: 'http' }

   # Print deprecation notices to the Rails logger.
   config.active_support.deprecation = :log
```

So in this case, I'm happy for the 'Cache-Control' line to be changed, but want the other 2 lines ('host..', 'config...') left alone.

I know how to choose either the old file or the new file, but what do you do when you want parts of both?  Do you just copy what you want to a separate file and paste in after the interactive process has finished, or is there a cleaner method?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the `app:update` process does not have an interactive way to edit. You just have to go back and edit it once the process is complete.

Looks like the easiest option for you in this case would be to choose your file in `app:update` and then copy the new cache control values in.

Comment: Thanks.  After I realised that running rails app:update resulted in the creation of a proposed new file ('development_something.rb') alongside the existing file ('development.rb') and allowed you to choose between the two, I realised I could just copy what I needed from the proposed new file into the existing file, and choose the existing file.

Answer (score 2):

I use `railsdiff.org` to compare the differences between different versions of rails

For example, `railsdiff.org/5.2.0/6.1.5` will give the rails framework changes between 5.2 and 6.1.5